# Retrieving Cognito Identity ID using credentialsProvider vs AWSMobileClient

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, amazon-cognito

**Why am I successfully getting getting Cognito ID when I use getIdentityID from credentials provider but get an error when using AWSMobileClient?**

I have setup a Federated Identity with a custom developer provider. I am initializing the Amazon Cognito credentials provider using the code snippet generated by the Amazon Cognito console.

```swift
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast1, identityPoolId: "IDENTITY_POOL_ID")
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

Following this, I am retrieving the cognito Identity ID using the following:

```swift
credentialsProvider.getIdentityId().continueWith(block: { (task) -> AnyObject? in
    if (task.error != nil) {
        print("Error: " + task.error!.localizedDescription)
    }
    else {
        // the task result will contain the identity id
        let cognitoId = task.result!
        print("Cognito id: \(cognitoId)")
    }
    return task;
})
```

When I run this, I successfully retrieve the identity ID, and I can also view it as an unauthenticated user on my console for the federated identity. However, when I try retrieving the identity ID using AWSMobileClient as follows:

```swift
AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().initialize { (userState, error) in
            if let userState = userState {
                print("UserState (AccountView): \(userState.rawValue)")
            } else if let error = error {
                print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        // Retrieve your Amazon Cognito ID
AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().getIdentityId().continueWith { task in
                    if let error = task.error {
                        print("error: \(error.localizedDescription) \((error as NSError).userInfo)")
                        print(error)
                    }
                    if let result = task.result {
                        print("identity id: \(result)")
                    }
                    return nil
                }
```

I get AWSMobileClient  error 30 : **error: cognitoIdentityPoolNotConfigured(message: "Cannot get identityId since cognito credentials configuration is not available.")**

Why is this? What am I missing?

I am using **AWSMobileClient, AWSCore**

**Environment(please complete the following information):**
 - SDK Version: 'AWSMobileClient', '~> 2.10.0',  'AWSCore', '~> 2.10.0'
 - Dependency Manager: Cocoapods
 - Swift Version : 5.0
 - Xcode Version: 10.3

**Device Information (please complete the following information):**
 - Device: MacOS 10.14.5
 - iOS 12.4

Comment: I've seen your question in the AWS forum, too. Have you been lucky enough to make any progress on this one?